# WEPAPI development requiring Newtonsoft.Json.dll

Tags: c#, .net, json, dll, asp.net-web-api

We are developing a new WEBAPI, which requires dll Package installation : **“Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi ” version 6.0** for assembly reference. As a part of this Newtonsoft.Json.dll is referenced to the project. 
Our Application already has “Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi ” version 4.5.
I even tried to use the older dll, but its not compatible with reset of the binaries in the WebAPI project.
If I override the older version with the newer version what could be the possible impact. I have used the old version in the Exception Handling wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

I've lost a good bunch of brain cells fighting similar issue for Owin-based WebAPI project. "Solution" I use is dependencies redirection in `app.config` file. Here is file from my solution, you can correct it to your needs.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http.Formatting" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Http" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.1.0" newVersion="3.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```